# How to retrieve value normally wired by @Value from WebApplicationContext in a Servlet?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, autowired

I usually annotate some value fields with `@Value`, e.g.

```
class NotASpringBean {
    @Value("${test.value}")
    String testValue;
}
```

Note no `@Component`, no XML entry for this class. That's the reason of trouble.
I wire it up with `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext`

I have to assign the would-have-been value of `testValue` w/o `@Value` (or in other words: w/o automatic class processing done by Spring usually).

I have a `WebApplicationContext` but don't know if it's possible to get the same value that `testValue` would receive?

---

To be precise, I have

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/props.properties"/>
```

in my root spring context and I need to access those properties in a Servlet.. and `@Value` doesn't work. I've worked around it with `@Autowired @Qualifier` combo, but I had to duplicate properties in XML by defining bean per property.

Also note: I **cannot** move the properties include to a different file.

Comment: Use the `Environment` class for that. Could you elaborate a little on why you don't can or want to use `@Value` or placeholders in xml to retrieve the value?

Comment: @M.Deinum Because the class is not Spring managed but I need a value from Spring properties ;) Could you give example of using `Environment` ?

Comment: It is probably easier to make the bean Spring Managed or read the properties yourself. You need to obtain the context, extract the `Environment` with `getEnvironment` and can use that to get the properties but that ties your class to spring.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add some.properties to Spring context:

   e.g. In your config class.

   ```
   @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholder() {
       PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
       bean.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("some.properties"));
       return bean;
   }
   ```
2. You need to retrieve `ApplicationContext` instance for #3:

   e.g.

   ```
   @Component
   class HogeContextAware implements org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware {
       @Override
       public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
           this.global.applicationContext = applicationContext;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Populate a `Bean` that is not Spring managed:

   e.g.

   ```
   ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableAppContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) global.applicationContext.getSpringContext();

   YourBean bean = new YourBean();
   configurableAppContext.getBeanFactory().autowireBean(bean);
   bean.getFooValue();
   ```

It works(, I guess).

Comment: For 1 the bean needs to be `public static` not just `public` and you really should be using a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: @sndyuk sorry, but I can't use your solution.. The properties are already loaded, included in root XML context. Can't be moved also..

Comment: @MerchukHul "The properties are already loaded". My answer #1 is a just a sample for loading properties. If It have been already loaded, You only do #2 and #3.